# how to get request data in ajax success callback method

Tags: ajax

I do ajax request in foreach and question is that how to get request data in success callback or how to match response data and request.
  Thank you in advance!

Comment: .done(function(data) { });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var makeRequest = function(data){
    doAjaxRequest(data, function(dataFromServer){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
array.forEach(function(element){
    makeRequest(element.getData());
}
```

What this does is for each `element` in `array`, the variable `data` is different because it refers to the local scope of the function `makeRequest`. This way, each callback refers to the proper `data`.